# Family tree from a pedigree file

Tags: r, family-tree, pedigree

I have a pedigree file that looks like this:

| FAMID | ID | MO | FA | SEX | AGE | BIRTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F0001 | C1 |  |  | 2 | 32 |  |
|  | C2 |  |  | 1 | 34 |  |
|  | C3 | C1 | C2 | 1 | 12 |  |
| F0002 | C4 |  |  | 2 | 44 |  |
|  | C5 | C4 | Q1 | 1 | 13 |  |
|  | C6 | C4 | Q1 | 1 | 12 |  |
|  | Q1 |  |  | 1 |  |  |

Similar to this i have 100 F ID's and I want to create Family tree in R using a CSV file which similar data that is in the table presented.

This is the code I have used in R

```
# Install (if necessary) and load the kinship2 package
## install.packages("kinship2")
library(kinship2)

# Read the pedigree data from the CSV file
pedigree_data <- read.csv("CHS_Pedigree_new.csv")
View(pedigree_data)
# Ensure that the column names are in the correct case
colnames(pedigree_data) <- toupper(colnames(pedigree_data))

pedigree <- pedigree(
  id = pedigree_data$ID, 
  momid = pedigree_data$MO, 
  dadid = pedigree_data$FA, 
  sex = pedigree_data$SEX
)
# Plot the pedigree tree
plot(pedigree)
```

but this is giving me an error saying Impossible tree, I have rechecked all my code but I cannot get the specifics out of it.

Comment: What do you mean "create Family tree"? Is that a plot, a network-graph (DAG), a frame with a different layout than above?

Comment: Like a pedigree tree, kind of a network tree

Comment: Either you're asking us to recommend a package, library, etc, which is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), or you're asking us to know what you want visually and to code it all for you, generally not how SO is intended to be used. For either of those, your question may be closed unless you show your effort and where it is falling short. In the meantime, consider https://github.com/lindsayrutter/ggenealogy (no longer on CRAN, authors are unresponsive) or, since a genealogy tree is really just a DAG, look into the `igraph` package. Good luck!

Comment: # Install and load the kinship2 package
install.packages("kinship2")
library(kinship2)

# Read the pedigree data from the CSV file
pedigree_data <- read.csv("CHS_Pedigree_new.csv")
View(pedigree_data)
# Ensure that the column names are in the correct case
colnames(pedigree_data) <- toupper(colnames(pedigree_data))

pedigree <- pedigree(
  id = pedigree_data$ID, 
  momid = pedigree_data$MO, 
  dadid = pedigree_data$FA, 
  sex = pedigree_data$SEX
)
# Plot the pedigree tree
plot(pedigree).

Comment: I have used this code but it giving me an error which is an impossible tree. I checked the whole file again and could not find what was wrong.

Comment: Code is really not good in comments, as you can see, plus comments can be skipped by readers or hidden by the Stack interface. Please [edit] your question and add that to a [code block]. Thanks!

Comment: Much better! It's making a lot more sense to me, thank you for your edits.

Comment: It looks to me like you are defining a variable called "pedigree", which has the same name as function pedigree(). How about changing the name of the variable to p, i.e. p = pedigree(...); plot(p) ?

Comment: I can't find the word "[Ii]mpossible" in the kinship2 source code. Can you please run `traceback()` after you get the error and edit your question to include the output? (It may be difficult to help you without a [mcve], but we'll try ...)

Comment: Your code [works fine for me](https://gist.github.com/zx8754/ff0e6ea629f05a9f77fd003b909318e7#file-so_77868111-r), provide reproducible example input data that would fail `dput(pedigree_data)`.